# How can I put 4 centered flexboxes with text above and below inside the main content of the Holy Grail layout?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, alignment

I can make the basic Holy Grail layout, but once it comes to putting boxes inside boxes, things fall apart. I have looked at code for comparison, but this specific layout doesn't seem very common.

What I want to do is have 4 flexboxes inside the main content of the webpage. Above the boxes is a header, maybe a paragraph underneath that. Under the flexboxes are a description for each, that is centered and aligned with the flexbox. The flexboxes will hold a picture, but that is not important right now.

https://codepen.io/ct2k/pen/mdqdpzw

```
}
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    text-align: center;
    color: #FFF;
}
.holy-grail header,
.holy-grail footer,
.hg-sidebar,
.holy-grail-content {
    padding: 20px;
}
.holy-grail header,
.holy-grail footer {
    background: #0c31aa;
}
.hg-sidebar {
    background: #b7d3ec;
}
.holy-grail-content {
    color: #777;
}

.holy-grail {
    min-height: 100vh;
}
.holy-grail,
.holy-grail-body {
    display: flex;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.holy-grail-content {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .holy-grail-sidebar-1 {
        order: -1;
    }
    .holy-grail-body {
        flex-direction: row;
    }
    .hg-sidebar {
        flex: 0 0 260px;
    }

.block {
    border: solid;
    border-color: cornflowerblue;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    font-size: 48px;
    text-align: center;
}

.mc {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can insert those divs of the card inside other major div

I try to solve it quickly using another div to store

- the header for the card
- paragraph
- card
- description of card

```css
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    text-align: center;
    color: #FFF;}
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    text-align: center;
    color: #FFF;
}
.holy-grail header,
.holy-grail footer,
.hg-sidebar,
.holy-grail-content {
    padding: 20px;
}
.holy-grail header,
.holy-grail footer {
    background: #0c31aa;
}
.hg-sidebar {
    background: #b7d3ec;
}
.holy-grail-content {
    color: #777;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
  /*Add this line*/
  flex-direction: column;
}

.holy-grail {
    min-height: 100vh;
}
.holy-grail,
.holy-grail-body {
    display: flex;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    flex-direction: column;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .holy-grail-sidebar-1 {
        order: -1;
    }
    .holy-grail-body {
        flex-direction: row;
    }
    .hg-sidebar {
        flex: 0 0 260px;
    }

.block {
    border: solid;
    border-color: cornflowerblue;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    font-size: 48px;
    text-align: center;
}

.mc {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
  
  .card-with-header-and-desc-container {
 text-align: center;
    width: 200px;
    /*height: 200px;*/
    
  }
  
   .card-with-header-and-desc-container__header {
 font-weight: 700;
     font-size: 1.5rem
  }
  
  .card-with-header-and-desc-container__sub {
 font-weight: 500;
     font-size: 1.1rem
  }
  
  .extra-text{
    margin: 0 10px;
  }
}
.holy-grail header,
.holy-grail footer,
.hg-sidebar,
.holy-grail-content {
    padding: 20px;
}
.holy-grail header,
.holy-grail footer {
    background: #0c31aa;
}
.hg-sidebar {
    background: #b7d3ec;
}
.holy-grail-content {
    color: #777;
}

.holy-grail {
    min-height: 100vh;
}
.holy-grail,
.holy-grail-body {
    display: flex;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.holy-grail-content {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .holy-grail-sidebar-1 {
        order: -1;
    }
    .holy-grail-body {
        flex-direction: row;
    }
    .hg-sidebar {
        flex: 0 0 260px;
    }

.block {
    border: solid;
    border-color: cornflowerblue;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    font-size: 48px;
    text-align: center;
}

.mc {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body class="holy-grail">
  <!--<body class="holy-grail">-->
  <header>
    <p>Header</p>
  </header>
  <div class="holy-grail-body">

    <section class="holy-grail-content">
      <h1>Main content</h1>
      <div class="mc">
        <div class="card-with-header-and-desc-container">
          <p class="card-with-header-and-desc-container__header">Some header</p>
          <p class="card-with-header-and-desc-container__sub">maybe a paragraph</p>
          <div class="block block1">1
          </div>
          <p>Description of each card Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. </p>
        </div>

        <p class="extra-text">Whats</p>

        <div class="card-with-header-and-desc-container">
          <p class="card-with-header-and-desc-container__header">Some header</p>
          <p class="card-with-header-and-desc-container__sub">maybe a paragraph</p>
          <div class="block block2">2
          </div>
          <p>Description of each card Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. </p>
        </div>

        <p class="extra-text">In</p>

        <div class="card-with-header-and-desc-container">
          <p class="card-with-header-and-desc-container__header">Some header</p>
          <p class="card-with-header-and-desc-container__sub">maybe a paragraph</p>
          <div class="block block3">3
          </div>
          <p>Description of each card Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. </p>
        </div>

        <p class="extra-text">The</p>

        <div class="card-with-header-and-desc-container">
          <p class="card-with-header-and-desc-container__header">Some header</p>
          <p class="card-with-header-and-desc-container__sub">maybe a paragraph</p>
          <div class="block block4">4
          </div>
          <p>Description of each card Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. </p>
        </div>

        <p class="extra-text">Box?</p>
      </div>
    </section>

    <div class="holy-grail-sidebar-1 hg-sidebar">
      <p>Sidebar 1</p>
    </div>

    <div class="holy-grail-sidebar-2 hg-sidebar">
      <p>Sidebar 2</p>
    </div>

  </div>

  <footer>
    <p>Footer</p>
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

[Example applied](https://codepen.io/saloavalos/pen/PoOoQXL)

if this does not solve your problem consider adding some images showing what your expected design is.

Comment: That is layout is very close to what I want, but the main content header is pushed to the far left side, thus the 4 boxes are not perfectly center. Once again I tried adjusting the main content flex height, but it does nothing. The flexbox inside the flexbox is taking up too much unecessary room. I don't have flex/grow on it, so it shouldn't do that.

Comment: I have added flex-direction: column; to the class .holy-grail-content and now main content is center